# How to make a completely automated chute?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I mine my ore much much above magma smelters. I am looking for a way of using gravity instead of brute dwarf-force to bring ore down to smelters.

All instructions on the internet involve micromanagement: either ore needs to be dumped or bridge needs to be retracted periodically.

Is there a way of making this process once and forever (until I lose, of course)?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a [Minecart Quantum Stockpile](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Exploit#The_Minecart_Stop), except it dumps to a vertical shaft.

The science in doing the dump is explained there, and it's easy to do, but there are 2 main precautions you should be aware of:

- If you don't dump to a stockpile, dwarves will just pick up those ores and go up again with them. So, on the bottom of the shaft, place a 1 square stockpile, that also links with your smelters.
- Projectiles fall at high speeds, and as such will injure your dwarves, should they be on the same square as the shaft. Consider adding a bridge or a floor hatch to stop the flow of rocks, or periodically stopping the dumping service.

Comment: I can also suggest you try to use some pressure traps to sequence the work. I'll try to develop this later on, though.